# Facebook android SDK not working on Android Platform version below 4.0

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

We had created multiple Android Apps using Facebooks Android SDK. It is working fine on 4.0 and above platforms but not working on anything below(we have checked on 2.3 and 3.0). Even the Facebook Android SDK 3.0 is not working on Android 2.3 and 3.0.

Following is the description:
1: Click on the login button on the Activity. Which opens the FBDialog for Authentication.
2: Enter the credentials
3: And hit enter/login.
4: Same page reloads.

Kindly let me know if someone is facing the same problem?

Comment: I too getting the same issue. Its working good in 4.X higher version but not in 2.3